# getting error-static const declarations in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective C.I am porting from c++ to objective c.

```
RSDS.h
------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "msg_remote.h"

@interface RSDS : NSObject {

}
@interface RS232Data : NSObject {

    unsigned char m_abTxMsgImage[RMH_MESSAGE_MAX_SIZE]; //
```

> Error:variably  modified
>   'm_abTxMsgImage' at file scope

```
}

msg_remote.h
------------
static const int RMH_MESSAGE_MAX_SIZE = 4096;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const int` in C does not work like it does in C++.  It merely declares a variable that you are not allowed to change and you are not therefore allowed to use it to size an array in an array declaration.

You have two choices to fix this.  Either recompile your application as Objective-C++ (do this by changing all the `.m` extensions to `.mm`) or turn your

```
static const int RMH_MESSAGE_MAX_SIZE = 4096;
```

to

```
#define RMH_MESSAGE_MAX_SIZE 4096
```

or you can do

```
enum 
{
    RMH_MESSAGE_MAX_SIZE = 4096
};
```